# mysql replication via ssh - failed

Tags: mysql, ssh, replication

I've set up an mysql replication following this guide: http://robpickering.com/2011/02/mysql-replication-over-an-ssh-tunnel-373

I configured my master and my slave, and set up a connection via autossh.

To test this, i logged into the master via the slave by the following command

```
 mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3305 -uslave_user -p
```

And yes, i could conncet.

Then i tried to restart the slave, but i got this

```
Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld.
Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
```

ok, i tried to have a look at the mysql.err file, but it is empty (/var/log/mysql.err)

am i looking at the wrong file or is there something strange going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out, that i had an error in my config file. No idea why it didn't showed up anywhere, but i found it out with the following command:

```
mysqld_safe --log-error=/var/log/mysql.err
```

This file than showed up, that i missspelled a config attribute in my my.cnf

Hope this will help someone!

Comment: You can verify the syntax of your my.cnf file for errors with the following command: mysqld --defaults-file="/etc/my.cnf" --help